# group base on array element mongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Explanation: how we can do the group based on array elements, I want to do a group based on 0 element of both arrays.

```
{
  "st": [
    [
      "2011-01-04T12:18:41Z",
      0
    ],
    [
      "2011-01-04T15:00:00Z",
      0
    ]
  ],
  "en": [
    [
      "2011-01-04T14:59:50Z",
      1
    ],
    [
      "2011-01-04T15:05:00Z",
      4
    ]
  ]
}
```

The expected output document looks like. for example

```
[
  {
    "st": "2011-01-04T12:18:41Z",
    "en": "2011-01-04T14:59:50Z",
    "st_val": 0,
    "en_val": 1,
    "total_index_count": 2
  }, 
  {
    "st": "2011-01-04T15:00:00Z",
    "en": "2011-01-04T15:05:00Z",
    "st_val": 0,
    "en_val": 4,
    "total_index_count": 2
  }
]
```

Comment: can you add another more complex example? i'm not sure i understand.
do you want to just match index `i` in `st` with index `i` in `en` arrays?

Comment: yes, I want to combine them both index `i` as one document.

Comment: Its very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68921898/merge-array-in-to-objects-into-mongodb/68926336#68926336) map on indexes and merge objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in several different ways, here is an approach utilizing the `$map` and `$arrayElemAt` operators.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      elements: {
        $map: {
          input: {
            $range: [
              0,
              {
                $size: "$st"
              }
            ]
          },
          in: {
            st_val: {
              "$arrayElemAt": [
                {
                  "$arrayElemAt": [
                    "$st",
                    "$$this"
                  ]
                },
                0
              ]
            },
            st: {
              "$arrayElemAt": [
                {
                  "$arrayElemAt": [
                    "$st",
                    "$$this"
                  ]
                },
                1
              ]
            },
            en_val: {
              "$arrayElemAt": [
                {
                  "$arrayElemAt": [
                    "$en",
                    "$$this"
                  ]
                },
                0
              ]
            },
            en: {
              "$arrayElemAt": [
                {
                  "$arrayElemAt": [
                    "$en",
                    "$$this"
                  ]
                },
                1
              ]
            },
            
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$elements"
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: "$elements"
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GYLyicTyqOA)

Comment: Its look fine, I have 2 questions. 
1. in the `project` stage how we can count the index of the array `total_index_count` is missing.
2. In `  "$range":[0,{ "$size": "$st"}] ` why you took `st` why not `en`

Comment: the assumption is they are both the same length, if not you should specify the behavior your expecting.

Comment: and i wasn't sure what `total_index_count` is because they are both `2` in the result you specified.

Comment: `st` and `en` both index always be equal. for example, if `st` has 2 indexes, `en` should be 2 indexes, so how we can count the index at the `project` stage is it then we need the group stage?

Comment: You mean like this:
https://mongoplayground.net/p/ofpDcRx8qyE
?

i'm not sure i understand what `total_index_count` reflects?

Comment: no, no,  here is showing 2 different numbers, I am saying `en` and `st` should have equal lengths of the array. so we have to count of the total length of `st` or `en`

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/EP-DQbI9_Kd, like so?